# What are real and transparent proxies

Tags: .net, remoting

In .NET remoting, there are two kind of proxies:

1. Transparent Proxies
2. Real Proxies

What is the difference between them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/dotnet/articles/ms973857(v=msdn.10)):

> The **TransparentProxy** is an internal class that cannot be replaced or
> extended. On the other hand, the RealProxy and ObjRef classes are
> public and can be extended and customized when necessary. The
> **RealProxy** class is an ideal candidate for performing load balancing
> for example, since it handles all function calls on a remote object.
> When Invoke is called, a class derived from RealProxy can obtain load
> information about servers on the network and route the call to an
> appropriate server. Simply request a MessageSink for the required
> ObjectURI from the Channel and call SyncProcessMessage or
> AsyncProcessMessage to forward the call to the required remote object.
> When the call returns, the RealProxy automatically handles the return
> parameter.
>
> Here's a code snippet that shows how to use a derived RealProxy class.
>
> ```
> MyRealProxy proxy = new MyRealProxy(typeof(Foo));
> Foo obj = (Foo)proxy.GetTransparentProxy();
> int result = obj.CallSomeMethod();
> ```
>
> The **TransparentProxy** obtained above can be forwarded to another
> application domain. When the second client attempts to call a method
> on the proxy, the remoting framework will attempt to create an
> instance of MyRealProxy, and if the assembly is available, all calls
> will be routed through this instance. If the assembly is not
> available, calls will be routed through the default remoting
> RealProxy.
>
> An ObjRef can easily be customized by providing replacements for
> default ObjRef properties TypeInfo, EnvoyInfo, and ChannelInfo. The
> following code shows how this can be done.
>
> ```
> public class ObjRef {
>   public virtual IRemotingTypeInfo TypeInfo 
>   {
>     get { return typeInfo;}
>     set { typeInfo = value;}
>   }
>
>   public virtual IEnvoyInfo EnvoyInfo
>   {
>     get { return envoyInfo;}
>     set { envoyInfo = value;}
>   }
>
>   public virtual IChannelInfo ChannelInfo 
>   {
>     get { return channelInfo;}
>     set { channelInfo = value;}
>   }
> }
> ```